# Ошибка в коде с++,

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, переопределение

```
#include < iostream >
#include < map >
#include < utility >
int main()
{
   std::map < int, int > m1;
   std::map < int, int > m2(m1);
   std::map < int, int > m3 = m1;

   typedef struct std::pair < int, int > PAIR;
   std::map < int, int > m1;
   m1.insert(PAIR(0, 10));
   m1.insert(PAIR(1, 20));
   std::map < int, int > m2(m1.begin(), m1.end());
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Ошибка в переопределении m2.

Comment: Ну да, и не только... а вопрос в чем? Вас же не удивляет ошибка в программе `int main(){ int x; int x; int x; }`?

Comment: меня тревожит то, как `typedef struct std::pair < int, int > PAIR;` скомпилировалось...

Comment: @KoVadim Как скомпилировалось? Молча :) https://ideone.com/NCCAHc

Comment: @Harry я умею пользоваться компилятором. я сижу и думаю над логическим смыслом этого.

Comment: @KoVadim А что вас удивляет? Ведь тип `pair` определен именно как `struct`, как я понимаю... Ну а `struct` можно писать, как и в C, нет?

Comment: я имел ввиду - как это скомпилировалось в уме у автора вопроса. Как он додумался до такого и что он вкладывал в это

Comment: так в чем в ошибка в этом коде?

Comment: @Harry Так в чем ошибка? У меня не запускается код, пишет переопределение m2

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что у вас одни и те же переменные - `m1` и `m2` - объявлены дважды.

```
std::map < int, int > m1;
std::map < int, int > m2(m1);

....
std::map < int, int > m1;

....
std::map < int, int > m2(m1.begin(), m1.end());

// Если тут написать, скажем, m2 = m1, то
// **какому** m2 - первому или второму - присвоить
// **какой** m1 - первый или второй?...
```

Comment: И как пофиксить?

Comment: Мама дала вам и вашему брату одно и то же имя. И теперь непонятно, кому из вас пришла повестка в армию... Как пофиксить? Ну включите же голову!

Comment: если оставить так ideone.com/NCCAHc

Comment: то правильно будет?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы хотите. Ваши комментарии соответствуют тому, что одного из братьев просто закопали... Второй вариант - ему дают другое имя :) Зависит от того, что вам нужно...

Comment: Мне просто нужно создать экземпляр класса map.

Comment: Мне просто нужно создать экземпляр класса map.

Comment: Ну что вы хотите?! Делайте! Потом мне нужно будет еще преподу рассказать, что и как делать? Я все разжевал, в рот положил - вы даже после этого проглотить не можете... Бегом за учебники!